# Use views attachment as a block

Tags: views

Is there a way to use the views attachment as its own block? I would like to take the attachment from the "Glossary" view and output it elsewhere on my site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try creating a block in a custom module using [hook_block_info](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7) and [hook_block_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7). Then use [views_embed_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7) to load the view and display it in your block.

This may look a little like this:

```
function my_module_block_info() {
  $blocks['glossary_attachment'] = array(
    'info' => t('Glossary Attachment'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
  );
  return $blocks;
}

function my_module_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();
  if ($delta == 'glossary_attachment') {
    $block['subject'] = t('Glossary Attachment');
    // Load the view.
    $view = views_embed_view('glossary', 'attachment');
    if ($view) {
      $block['content'] = $view;
    }
    else {
      $block['content'] = t('The view is empty');
    }
  }
  return $block;
}
```

Comment: Can you answer this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497392/attach-or-embed-node-add-form-with-a-view)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's possible to add a "Block" display to the same view ( Via add new Display tab ) and then to add the block to a page from Admin > Structure > Blocks

Comment: Unfortunately, I think doing that will mean I loose the contextual filters. So the ability to filter goes away.